# Efficiently & Programmatically Altering a Word Document's Text Based On Audience Type

Tags: ms-word

I have several Word documents that contain language that needs to be slightly changed based on whether they're being shared with Audience A or Audience B.

Currently, I'm in the unenviable position of manually altering these documents whenever changes need to be made, or new drafts are produced, which is an incredibly tedious and error-prone process.

Is there some way to programmatically do this in Word?

Ideally, I'd like to have a document with "binary switches" built into it that allows me select the Audience type and quickly auto-generate a new document.

I've never done any serious "coding" in Microsoft Word before, so my apologies if the answer here is blindingly obvious or trivially implemented.  I'm not looking for anyone to hold my hand (or offer up copy & paste-able code): just point me in the general direction of the resources, tools, and techniques I need to get this job done and I'll happily take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single document that includes alternate text. Assign a bookmark to each piece of text. Then use a VBA macro to make the bookmarked text visible or invisible.

```
With ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("TextA1").Range.Font.Hidden = True
    .Bookmarks("TextB1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    .Bookmarks("TextA2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
    .Bookmarks("TextB2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
End With
```

Documents with hidden text are easier to edit if you use **File>Options>Display>Hidden Text**. The hidden text becomes visible, but has a dotted underline.

Comment: Thank you, John.  This was extremely helpful!  I've been meaning to "get around" to learning VBA for a while but something new & shiny always seems to grab my attention first.